# how to delete entity from google appengine using ids

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get the post entity using ID but everytime I try to run this code I get an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete. I've tried using every method and variation but no luck.

```
   post_id = self.request.get("post_id")
   q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ID='" + post_id + "'").get()
   q.delete()
```

Comment: No need to edit the title to mark it "solved". Just accept the answer (the checkmark below the answer's score).

Comment: Hey @DanCornilescu I have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: I, ok, I forgot about that, never mind. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Here is what I did:

```
post = Post.get_by_id(int(post_id))
post.delete()
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Python_Deleting_entities